# How to copy array of files (3,500) from directory A to Directory B

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I have 3,508 files with different names that need to copy from directory a to directory b.

Have tried:

```
Copy-Item "C:\users\username\directory-a\file-1.jpeg,file-2.jpeg" -Destination "C:\users\username\directory-b\"
```

Powershell will give error on file separation.

Comment: if you need to copy all files in folder try to use `robocopy 'source_path' 'destination_path' /mir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell will take an array of filenames as the `-Path`, `-LiteralPath`, or `-Include` parameter; however, if you are providing multiple filenames separated by commas, each one must be quoted *separately* - your example provides only a single file name that contains commas. Instead, use

```
Copy-Item "C:\users\username\directory-a\file-1.jpeg","C:\users\username\directory-a\file-2.jpeg" -Destination "C:\users\username\directory-b\"
```

or

```
Copy-Item "C:\users\username\directory-a\*" -Include "file-1.jpeg","file-2.jpeg" -Destination "C:\users\username\directory-b\"
```

You can pass a variable that is an array of file names to any of the parameters I mentioned above, e.g.,

```
$files = (Get-Content C:\User\Me\List-of-files.txt)
Copy-Item -Path $Files -Destination D:\New-Folder
```

The documentation for [`Copy-Item` at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6) does not make this clear.